# How can I ensure ion-content starts from where ion-navbar ends

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have got the situation where ion-content is covered up by ion-navbar. Is there some sort of attribute to tell ion-content that there is ion-bar present so its pushed below it.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<jt-navbar>
    <jt-navbar-left>
        <jt-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </jt-button>
        <jt-button (click)="goBack()" [hidden]="false">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon> 
        </jt-button>
    </jt-navbar-left>
    <jt-navbar-center>
        <jt-heading [level]="1">
            <jt-h1>{{pageTitle}}</jt-h1>
        </jt-heading>
    </jt-navbar-center>
    <jt-navbar-right>
        <p>{{ wishListCount }}</p>
        <jt-heart-button [count]="wishListCount" [buttonPlacement]="wishListButtonPlacement"></jt-heart-button>  
    </jt-navbar-right>
</jt-navbar>

<ion-nav id="content" [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" style="margin:80px 0px 0px 0px;"></ion-nav>
```

jt-navbar is pulling in ion-navbar

```
<ion-navbar *navbar class="jt-navbar">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="left">
            <ng-content select="jt-navbar-left"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <ng-content select="jt-navbar-center"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <ng-content select="jt-navbar-right"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <ng-content select="jt-navbar-bottom"></ng-content>
    </div>
</ion-navbar>
```

As you can see am forcing the "main content" down by inline style, which isn't ideal.

Comment: This sounds like a strange situation. Maybe provide some code snippets or a Plunker example of your HTML and CSS so anybody who wants to help has a better idea of what might be wrong

Comment: Code snippet added to question

Comment: Generally providing in Plunker is easy so that one can test it without having to set up.